# Unable to wake computer from sleep/hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, sleep, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

Samsung Chronos 7 laptop (Intel core i7) running Windows 8.1

**Issue:**

- laptop won't wake from sleep/hibernate
- with hibernate the display does not shut off, screen black, unable to wake
- with sleep (and hibernate off) the laptop will shut down on its own
- Event Viewer logs: `Windows failed to resume from hibernate with error status 0xC000007B`

**Fixes attempted:**

Remove hibernate

- `powercfg -h off` and `powercfg.exe /hibernate off`
- removed hibernate, leaving sleep. Laptop shuts off while in sleep mode.
- power options/sleep settings ignored

Display adapter

- disable Intel HD Graphics 4000; no noticeable effect
- update drivers; no noticeable effect

**Additional information:**

Event Viewer -

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was:
> 0x0000009f (0x0000000000000003, 0xffffe000b9f6f9c0,
> 0xffffd0014dcfacb0, 0xffffe000c1f23e10). A dump was saved in:
> C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 012416-75671-01.

Who Crashed -

> On Sun 1/24/2016 2:41:33 PM GMT your computer crashed crash dump file:
>
> C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\012416-75671-01.dmp This was probably caused by
> the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x14E2A0)
>
> Bugcheck code: 0x9F
> (0x3, 0xFFFFE000B9F6F9C0, 0xFFFFD0014DCFACB0, 0xFFFFE000C1F23E10)
>
> Error: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE file path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntoskrnl.exe product: Microsoft® Windows®
>
> Operating System company: Microsoft Corporation
>
> description: NT Kernel & System
>
> Bug check description: This bug check indicates that the
> driver is in an inconsistent or invalid power state. This appears to
> be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a
> hardware problem.  The crash took place in the Windows kernel.
> Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be
> identified at this time.

Dump -

- analysis [C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\012416-75671-01.dmp](http://pastebin.com/qyaWtGeV)
- [Dump file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53529463/012416-75671-01.dmp)

**Edit/Update**
In attempting to fix this issue, my laptop went into and endless boot cycle and I had to do perform a repair installation. This essentially 'reset' my laptop, without a full reformat. What I discovered is that the Samsung settings software may be the culprit. As I took several days to update my machine back to it's prior state, the hibernation was working properly. However, when I installed the Samsung settings app (I will update with the actual name), hibernation was removed as an option in power settings. With these laptops, you need the Samsung software to use some of the specific keyboard features. Now, my machine will sometimes go to sleep, but occasionally something interferes with auto sleep settings.

Comment: share the file C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\012416-75671-01.dmp so that I can analyze it

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I added the dump analysis above. I'm waiting on a visual studio update before pasting the raw.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - dump file added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, the dumps shows that the tunnel.sys causes it:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe000b9f6f9c0, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd0014dcfacb0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe000c1f23e10, The blocked IRP


6: kd> !irp ffffe000c1f23e10
Irp is active with 3 stacks 2 is current (= 0xffffe000c1f23f28)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe000bc345050 00000000 fffff802df7edb3c-ffffe000afb149c0 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\tunnel   nt!PopSystemIrpCompletion
            Args: 00014400 00000000 00000004 00000002
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffe000afb149c0    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

This is a [known issue in Windows 8.1, that Microsoft already tried to fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3078405). But I can see that you have the fix already installed. Your `tunnel.sys` has the version `6.3.9600.18048`. You should contact the Microsoft support and tell them that the update doesn't fix it.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. I'll report it. Now I've got bigger issues - I used the driver verifier `cmd: verifier` and now I'm in an endless BSOD kernel trap loop. Restore isn't working, so now I've got to figure that out.

Comment: boot from a Windows DVD, go to repair options, open command prompt, run regedit.exe, load the offline SYSTEM hive from C:\windows\system32\config, and delete this entries: http://superuser.com/a/1006537/174557