# Windows 10 Stuck in bsod loop DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, drivers, ssd

I was using my computer under medium load and suddently got a BSOD. Now i can't boot, i get same BSOD over and over again before i can get into windows and it's stuck in a loop so it doesn't enter into recovery mode by itself.

I got a win10 usb key so i used this to get into recovery mode and i have access to command prompt right now

- ]SFC /scannow fails with error "There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete. Restart windows and run sfc again."
- DISM doesnt work
- Can't get into safe mode
- /bcdedit will not work and bcdedit /enum says "the boot configuration data store could not be opened. The requested system device cannot be found"
- in command prompt, if i type "cd C:" it doesn't work and i can't see the root of my win10 ssd. however i can access other drivers
- in bios, my 960 pro SSD is still detected in the boot devices
- /fixmbr and /fixboot completed successfully but didnt fix the issue

Possible causes? :

- I recently upgraded to a Samsung 960 pro NVME SSD few weeks ago. Maybe it's dead ?
- I had an automatic nvidia driver upgrade today, i was asked to reboot and clicked "later". Then BSOD. Maybe corrupted driver because the update couldnt finish ? Sometimes driver upgrades are trigerred in the background when rebooting.
- Usual noob errors excluded here. I'm an experienced IT, this was a 100% stable machine all hardware tested and operating 24/7 since 9 months. Drivers were up to date, ram is memtested, cpu is stresstested, ssd was tested and benchmarked w ssd magician and hdd sentinel, windows was up to date, no malwares, no virus, etc.

config:
Windows 10 Pro
i7-6950x
gtx 1080 titan x pascal
samsung 960 pro nvme
msi x99a

i'd really appreciate some help. Thanks !

Comment: There is absolutely no chance your SSD is dead.

Comment: [disable driver verifier](https://superuser.com/a/1006537/174557). load offline registry in regedit.exe started from boot repair options and delete the values

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar(mine did not BSOD Loop thought) after a driver update. I turned off the Driver Verifier in the command prompt.

once at Command Prompt type verifier /bootmode resetonbootfail. Then press enter.

I found this article and it helped.[Enable disable Driver verifier from Widows 10 forums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5470-enable-disable-driver-verifier-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 1):

"Can't get into safe mode"

How did you do that?

Keep pressing "shift" and restart the machine or boot from a Windows 10 installation media and choose "Fix your computer", then choose "Troubleshoot", "Advanced", "Startup options", "safe mode". Then check the symptom again.

Answer (score 1):

Running the command `verifier.exe /reset` is key to breaking out of the loop. This however is not as straightforward as it seems.

In my case, running this command had no effect at all. Windows simply restarted the verifier on boot as if nothing had changed. I think this is because I entered it on the command prompt option of the windows troubleshooter. I figured it needs an elevated command prompt so I thought I will login to my account using safe mode, launch elevated command prompt from there and then enter the command. But Windows just refused to accept my password when I tried logging in via safe mode. More research led to the understanding that in safe mode Windows needs you to enter the local password, not your Microsoft account password (The local password is the one that you used when you installed Windows for the first time, before you linked it with your MS account). There is no point entering your MS account password or resetting it. It will only reset the password in the MS cloud, not your local password.

Naturally I didn't remember the local password since I hadn't used it in years. Then I found [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/96630/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-windows-password-the-easy-way/) neat trick to use the Sticky Keys function to launch an elevated command prompt. Summarizing here:

Open the Windows troubleshooter command prompt.

Type in the following command to backup the original sticky keys file:

```
copy c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe c:\
```

Then you’ll copy the command prompt executable (cmd.exe) over top of the sticky keys executable:

```
copy c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe
```

Reboot the PC.

Choose Safe Mode and on reaching the login screen tap the Shift key 5 times.

An elevated command prompt should open. Now you can enter the command `verifier.exe /reset`.

Follow the prompts and restart the computer. It should break out of the driver verifier loop.